# Is Webplatform.org's forum powered by StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, clone

Since it's launch last Monday I've heard a lot about WebPlatform. For those of you that don't know about it, WebPlatform describes itself as a "a new community-driven site that aims to become a comprehensive and authoritative source for web developer documentation."

So I was looking around and when I came to their forum (which they also title Q&A in various parts of the site), I was immediately struck by the SO-like interface. 
http://talk.webplatform.org/forums/

WebPlatform lists their stewards as: Adobe, Apple, Facebook, Google, HP, Microsoft, Mozilla, Nokia, Opera, and W3C, but I saw no mention of SO. In their [FAQ](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/WPD:FAQ), they say:

> What technology is the site implemented on?
>
> webplatform.org is completely built on open source technologies.
>
> Web Platform Docs uses MediaWiki (which also powers Wikipedia) to run.
>   It uses the Semantic MediaWiki and Semantic Forms extensions to apply
>   more structure to the content and make it easier to edit.
>
> Our Blog is built on WordPress.

Again, no mention of SO at all, however the resemblance is undeniable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the sourcecode of the page you linked:

```
<!-- Powered by Question2Answer - http://www.question2answer.org/ -->
```

[Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/) is one of the [many OSS clones of the Stack Overflow model](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267).

Comment: And from having tried to use it the past few days, that clone is absolutely *horrible*.

Comment: @casperOne: I just saw the editor. My eyes! Oh, my poor, poor eyes.